# Flex+MXML id property naming conventions / best practices

Tags: apache-flex, naming-conventions, mxml

Since there's so much potential pollution within namespaces, particularly with the parser automatically declaring any MXML component with an id to be publicly-accessible using that ID I'm finding it dangerous to use just camelCase for MXML element ids.

eg:

```
<mx:TextInput id="textOne" text="This is a test" />
<mx:Button id="buttonOne" label="Click Me" click="textOne.text='Testing 1-2-3'" />
```

In this rather trivial example, it's pretty clear that "textOne" in the Button's click handler is referring to the TextInput with an id of "textOne". It becomes less obvious in the following example:

```
<mx:Button id="buttonTwo" label="Change Tab" click="tabNav.selectedChild=newState" />
```

It's not at all obvious here that "newState" is referring to an INavigationContent instance with an id of "newState" within a TabNavigator context with an id of "tabNav".

This would become even less clear if we were doing this within an fx:Script block, or worse (better) within an external AS class file.

```
public function buttonClickHandler(event:FlexEvent):void {
    tabNav.selectedChild = newState;
}
```

Nowhere in this AS class file have we declared tabNav or newState, and so, at first glance, we expect the parser to complain. But it doesn't because these ids are automagically declared as public properties.

What I'm getting at is it *feels* to me that we should develop a convention that makes it more obvious where these public properties are coming from. Something like

```
id="mxTabNav"
```

or

```
id="TXTMyTextInput"
```

or maybe just use underscores

```
id="my_text_input"
```

In Flash development, a lot of us did this for (automatically) declared stage instances like "mcMyTabBar" or "navMC" or "playPauseBTN".

I'm looking for input from the Flex community about this. Am I just overthinking things? All of the related Style Guides and best practices documents I've read on the topic just say "use camelCase for ids, and make sure the id property is the first property".

What's your take?

Comment: a bit off topic, but Flex Formatter could help you keep the id attribute always first: http://sourceforge.net/projects/flexformatter/

Answer (score 1):

My take is that it's not really that big a deal.

All my components are encapsulated (as much as possible), I don't even give IDs to elements in MXML unless I really have to (i.e. something in the code behind module is referencing it).

I'd rather a class interacted with my component via

```
myComponent.foo(bar);
```

where the function sets the text on the myFooComponent

rather than

```
myComponent.myFooComponent.text = bar;
```

You can take this a step further if you don't reference the MXML file at all. We have View classes written in AS which all extend Group. In their createChildren functions, we add the component written in the MXML file.

This means nothing is targeting the MXML file directly (unless they start rooting through the display list, which gets a swift rap on the knuckles), and the View Class encapsulates the View object completely.

We even take this a step further and only ever reference View Classes by their Interfaces, so we can have multiple implementations of a view (say for customer specific changes) very easily.

Comment: Your approach does line up with my own philosophy of separating view from code. But unless you're doing all your layout in pure AS, at some point you will need a reference to the id of the MXML tag, which won't be explicitly declared in your Class. The moment you start trying to match a layout to something a designer has done, pure AS classes are no longer practical or even desirable from a workflow perspective. If you have a textinput in the top right corner to match a design, you'll still need to define it in MXML, and thus will need to refer to "myTextBox", and thus my OP

Comment: but the only thing that should refer to it is your code behind AS class (which is how we do it). MXML is purely for layout, AS is for logic

Comment: I totally agree with you, but maybe I'm not communicating my point properly. This is not about where to put code, but about coming up with a consistent naming convention for IDs in MXML. Looks like you don't feel there's any issue worth worrying about. Fair enough.

Comment: yeah pretty much. My point is that given the MXML is only ever going to be referenced by one other class, naming conventions for the ids aren't such a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use couple "purpose and class name" for id "". For example:

```
printButton, loggerTextArea, resultsDataGrid, etc
```

and for event handlers use "on" pattern. For example:

```
onPrintButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void
onLoggerTextAreaChange(event:Event):void
onResultsDataGridSelect(event:Event):void
```

1. Because it starts with "on" it's clear that the method is event handler
2. It has Component name in handler name - now it's clear who triggers event
3. It has information about event type - Click, Change, Select ... so its clear what kind of event it is...

Comment: I _do_ agree with adding "on" to the event handler. I'm not sure though that the naming convention for "id" addresses the issue I'm raising in my OP.